# ¿Cuál es el significado real de la palabra "Poporote"?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, definiciones, palabras-raras

Ayer, conversando con un compañero, salio a relucir una palabra que hasta ahora no he encontrado un significado real para ella, "***Poporote***".

¿De donde proviene? y ¿Cuál es su origen?

La verdad me tiene muy intrigado, jamás la había escuchado.

si alguno de ustedes me saca de dudas, agradecido.

Comment: ¿Es posible que fuese "boborote"? Según el diccionario de americanismos significa "persona torpe" en algunas zonas de Venezuela.

Comment: Por favor Dave, danos un poquito de contexto.

Comment: Sería posible saber de dónde es la persona que dijo esa palabra? Mira que en el stack usamos tags para ciertos países. Quizá se usa en uno pero no en otro. Mi consejo es que preguntes directamente a esa persona, y luego vengas y respondas tu propia pregunta con esa información. Nos ayudarás a aprender algo nuevo a todos.

Comment: I would have voted to close as unclear if someone hadn't miraculously come up with a great answer. // Please see related post on Meta: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2891/9385

Comment: Es correcto. Soy de Caracas y he escuchado mucho la palabra “poporote” para referirse a alguien como “tonto”.

Answer (score 6):

*Poporote* es una palabra que se usa en la jerga caraqueña (jerga de capital, jerga de Caracas) de Venezuela y significa:

- Zoquete, tonto
- Persona grande y tonta
- Súper-tonto
- Súper-zoquete

Answer (score 1):

Una especulación: la palabra *poporote* bien podría ser un aumentativo o intensificador de ***poporo***.

Como se indica en [Fondéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-palabra-poporo-4104/), un *poporo* es simplemente un "chichón" en la cabeza, aunque la palabra se restringía a Venezuela (es de origen caribe) y dejó de usarse hace tiempo.

O sea, *poporote* significaría literalmente "grandísimo chichón", y su valor de "tonto" vendría por el lado del "aturdimiento" que te produce un golpe en la cabeza.

Y probablemente en su origen haya tenido relación con otro *poporo* más antiguo, que es una calabaza o vasija que acompaña al hábito de mascar coca, y del cual es fácil encontrar información en internet. (Las vasijas y las calabazas suelen acompañar a la cabeza en los juegos de palabras: el mate, la testa, el coco).

(No tengo cómo confirmar las dos ideas anteriores, las planteo solo como posibilidad y porque esto es entretenido. Lo de "gran chichón" me parece posible. Que derive de "calabaza" es dudoso).

Answer (score 1):

En Los Andes de Venezuela, en Mérida exactamente, se usa la palabra ***poporotudo*** para denotar una prominencia o hinchazón en alguna parte del cuerpo producto o no de un golpe y que suele ser doloroso, como por ejemplo los nudos dolorosos que se forman en las articulaciones de los dedos de las manos como consecuencias de la artritis.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que preguntan, no solo el significado, sino también el origen, de dónde viene, etc.